# server to server transfer

Tags: ssh, cpanel, winscp

Need to transfer 1 file from old host with no SSH access to a new host in which I do have SSH access.  Having a hard time figuring this out.  Looking for a simple answer if there is one.  And also trying to avoid the slow upload times from my local machine, hence the reason for server to server transfer needed.

Comment: See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_fxp

Answer (score 1):

Are you able use FTP? You could use that to transfer the files.

Comment: well yes, but how would I ftp from one server directly to another.  I could download ftp the file to my local machine, then upload ftp from local to the new server, however at 100kb/s upload speed 2-3Gb is gonna take a while, and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: This can fix for large files directly if one no has SSH access.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the URL of the file you want to move from your old host, you can use the `wget` command in your SSH terminal. You can use this for any file extension, or folders if you want.

For example, if you want to move `http://www.yourhost.com/file.zip` to your new host, you would SSH into the folder you want to download move this to, and type:

```
    wget http://www.yourhost.com/file.zip
```

Comment: This will not fix due `memory_limit();`